# How to customize crystal_servlet_uri?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc, crystal-reports

I am having a problem with Crystal Report in JSP.

The report is viewed 1st page successfully, but I could not be viewed the next page, or export.
I've used a tool to catch the error. I realize that the error cause by invalid request.
For example my project url: http://localhost:8080/myproject, but when we navigate to next page or export report, it request to http://localhost:8080/CrystalReportViewerHandler.
It should be http://localhost:8080/myproject/CrystalReportViewerHandler.

What I have tried is put crystal_servlet_uri in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>crystal_servlet_uri</param-name>
    <param-value>/myproject/CrystalReportViewerHandler</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, the request is not change (still http://localhost:8080/CrystalReportViewerHandler).
Does any one know another solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this exact same problem.  The only solution I have found that works is to place your CrystalReportsViewer.jsp in the document root of the project.  As soon as you place it anywhere *under* WEB-INF, the 'myproject' is dropped from subsequent calls (like next page).

However, if the JSP you use to create and process the CrystalReportViewer object is placed alongside WEB-INF (not in it), then the 'myproject' re-appears and everything works.  (Or at least it did for me.)

This is maybe not the best news from a security perspective, but the requester must already have a ReportClientDocument to pass to this JSP, and that part you can control access to.

Comment: I'm not sure how controller return to that view (CrystalReportViewer.jsp).
For my current solution is deploy my project to ROOT directory of Tomcat.